# How to customize predefined elements

Tags: css, polymer, shadow-dom

I want to change the color values of the polymer [paper-input](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container).

I read the [guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html), but it didn't made sense for me.
I never worked with CSS variables, but this is what should be done according to the [Mozilla CSS specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)

```
// For shadow DOM
body /deep/ .gold-cc-cvc-input::shadow {
    --paper-input-container-focus-color: $color;
    --paper-input-container-color: $color;
    --paper-input-container-invalid-color: $color;
    --paper-input-container-input-color: $color;

    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I tried to execute the CSS variables, but the styles don't apply.

I'm running in circles here, would be awesome if someone with polymer experience could help me.

Comment: [Episode 17](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omASiF85JzI) of the Polycasts explains how to theme your elements and should help you with this.

Comment: @benhjt thanks for the reply, is there also a way to use a css file instead of the style tag and link import, since I use scss and have to compile it and bringing the compiled stuff in the usable format is kind of annoying?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have an answer for that. All I know is it needs to go into a HTML import inside a `<style is="custom-style"></style>`

Answer (score 1):

Well, the only thing that is missing here is the fact that you need the `is="custom-style"` attribute on your styles.

```
  <style is="custom-style">..</style>
```

Also `body /deep/ .gold-cc-cvc-input::shadow` doesn't work for some reason, I ended up using `:root .gold-cc-cvc-input` instead.

Final code:

```
:root .forms-input  {
    --paper-input-container-focus-color: $color;
    --paper-input-container-color: $color;
    --paper-input-container-invalid-color: $color;
    --paper-input-container-input-color: $color;
}
```

If someone from the Polymer team reads this: PS: You documentation needs complete code examples, it is very hard to guess anything there. Less Text More Code !